# How to get some value from object array? JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have:

> [Object, Object]
>
> 0:Object
>
> val1 : "123"
>
> name: "John"
>
> 1:Object:
>
> val2 : "123"
>
> name: "John"

How i can get values from this array object? I  need name values from this two object.

Comment: Please post yout code, not console.log() result ;)

Comment: Define `values`?

Comment: `array.map( object => object.name )`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and directly return `obj.name` property:

```js
const arr = [{val: "123", name: "John"}, {val: "123", name: "John"}];
const result = arr.map(obj => obj.name);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as the following code:

```js
const array = [{val: "123", name: "John"}, {val: "123", name: "John"}];

const res = array.map(e => e.name);

console.log(res);
```